# Can't access to correct object position

Tags: javascript

I'm tryng to get a specific object position like this:

```
workingPlan[selDayName]
```

the `workingPlan` object contain this structure:

```
Object {monday: null, tuesday: Object, wednesday: null, thursday: Object, friday: null…}
friday: null
monday: null
saturday: Object
sunday: null
thursday: Object
tuesday: Object
wednesday: null
__proto__: Object
```

How you can see the working plan contains all the week days, the day like: `saturday, thursday, tuesday` are working day 'cause are valorized and contains the `start` and `end` property but this isn't important now.

`selDayName` contains instead the current day, with this structure:

```
fri oct 23 2015 00:00:00 gmt+0000
```

now when I do this: `workingPlan[selDayName]` I want get the current day in the working plan, 'cause I need to display the unavailable period for each operator. The problem's that this code return:

> undefined

as response in chrome console. I don't know why. But I'm waiting this response: `null.` 
What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE - Full object structure:**

```
{
    "monday" : null,
    "tuesday" : {
        "start" : "09:00",
        "end" : "18:00",
        "breaks" : [{
                "start" : "11:20",
                "end" : "11:30"
            }, {
                "start" : "14:30",
                "end" : "15:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    "wednesday" : null,
    "thursday" : {
        "start" : "09:00",
        "end" : "18:00",
        "breaks" : [{
                "start" : "11:20",
                "end" : "11:30"
            }, {
                "start" : "14:30",
                "end" : "15:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    "friday" : null,
    "saturday" : {
        "start" : "09:00",
        "end" : "18:00",
        "breaks" : [{
                "start" : "11:20",
                "end" : "11:30"
            }, {
                "start" : "14:30",
                "end" : "15:00"
            }
        ]
    },
    "sunday" : null
}
```

**DATE PARSE**

```
var selDayName = $calendar.fullCalendar('getView')
                                    .start.toString('dddd').toLowerCase();
```

Maybe I should insert the code above from the topic start, sorry for this.

Comment: Your object structure is explained poorly (even if with many words). Please, type **`console.log(JSON.stringify(workingPlan))`** and post the outputed results here.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the question.

Comment: If I get you right, you want to get the week day based on the `selDayName` which is a `Date` object. But week day has a start and end times, so what is the rule ?

Comment: You're attempting to look something up by property, where the property name is `friday`, and you're passing `fri oct 23 2015 00:00:00 gmt+0000` as the property.  It's (obviously) not the same.  Are you able to parse out just the day before passing in the whole date object (assuming that's what you're doing) to `selDayName`?

Comment: Working plan contain also a date object, how you can see the day are the property that contain's another object structure with start and end date. If I pass the selDayName to index should return the correspond day I guess

Comment: It looks like `selDayName` is a `Date` object (which represents a timestamp, and does *not* get stringified to a week day name), not a day name (as its name suggests)

Comment: Guys see my update 'cause already parse the date for get the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `selDayName` is a `Date` object. However, your array contains data for days of week. You cannot simply pass `Date` and expect that it will work :)

You can get a date of week using `Date.getDay()` method - it returns an integer from 0 (Sunday) to 6 (Saturday). Then, you can map it to your values.

```
var daysOfWeek = ["sunday", "monday", "tuesday", "wednesday", "thursday", "friday", "saturday"];

var dayOfWeek = daysOfWeek[selDayName.getDay()]; // "sunday", "tuesday", "friday" etc.

var workingPlanForDay = workingPlan[dayOfWeek]; // null or object, if exists

console.log(workingPlanForDay);
```

Comment: Sure but I already do this: var selDayName = $calendar.fullCalendar('getView')
                                        .start.toString('dddd').toLowerCase(); for parse the date and it return the complete date.

Comment: @Dillinger It is strange. Then, why do you have `fri oct 23 2015 00:00:00 gmt+0000` in your `selDayName`? :)

Comment: Cause is taken by: $('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start that's return the start date of current view. Actually is a day view so return this day "friday" with complete date... But the parse seems not working

Answer (score 1):

I've fixed the issue adding:

```
$calendar.fullCalendar('getView').start.toDate().toString('dddd').toLowerCase();
```